# How to view and manage clipboard contents in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, clipboard

Is there functionality integrated into Windows 10 that would allow users to display the contents of their clipboards? I would like to view and manage current as well as previous content. It would also be helpful to view file sizes and types of entries.

Comment: That capability will be officially available tomorrow (2 Oct 2018) when the Windows 10 version 1809 update is formally released:  [Using Windows 10’s New Clipboard History and Cloud Sync](https://www.howtogeek.com/351978/using-windows-10s-new-clipboard-history-and-cloud-sync/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there functionality integrated into Windows 10 that would allow
>   users to display the contents of their clipboards?

Yes, that capability is officially available today (2 Oct 2018) now that the [Windows 10 version 1809](https://www.howtogeek.com/353165/whats-new-in-windows-10s-redstone-5-update-available-fall-2018/) Feature Update has been [formally released](https://www.howtogeek.com/367828/windows-10s-october-2018-update-is-out-now-the-best-features-and-how-to-get-it/).

> After the update is installed, navigate to **Start** > **Settings** >
>   **System** > **Clipboard** and you will see the following:
>
> [image: Clipboard Settings]
>
> You will need to manually enable this new function by changing the
>   slider under **Save multiple items** to **On**.
>
> [image: Save multiple items]
>
> Once it's enabled and you have copied several items to your clipboard,
>   you can view the contents by pressing
>   <kbd>[image: Winkey]</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.  You can then paste, pin,
>   or remove an item from your clipboard history:
>
> [image: Clipboard history]
>
> Initially, this function will support text, HTML, and image files
>   under 4 MB. Anything larger than that won't be kept within your
>   clipboard history.

---

**Sources**:
[Using Windows 10’s New Clipboard: History and Cloud Sync](https://www.howtogeek.com/351978/using-windows-10s-new-clipboard-history-and-cloud-sync/)
[Microsoft's Windows 10 'Redstone 5' build introduces cloud clipboard](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsofts-windows-10-redstone-5-build-introduces-cloud-clipboard/)